# Binary Classification

Tags: machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

I wanted to start off by saying this is not an exact duplicate of the other question. I checked it and it didn't have what I urgently need.
So here is the problem. I have a dataset with 30 features and 100000 rows of train data. I want to make a Binary classification model which determines whether the person is eligible or not for membership at our club. I am a rookie data scientist, and binary classification is a first for me. So please help me and tell me which model would be the most accurate for this purpose. Also, the time taken by the model to train doesn't matter... Thank you so much

update:
Ok, I have used logistic regression and instead of giving some members as accepted(1) it is showing me al members do not get the membership...So I thought there might be a mistake in choosing the Model, so I am looking for other models...

Comment: You can use any classification model for binary classification. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: Ok, I have used logistic regression and instead of giving some members as accepted(1) it is showing me al members do not get the membership...So I thought there might be a mistake in choosing the Model, so I am looking for other models...

Comment: Out of your 1000000 rows, how many have membership and how many don't have ?

Comment: 14000 have membership, the rest dont

Comment: 14% of your data points are labeled as Class A (Accepted) and 86% is labelled as Class N (Not Accepted) just by looking at that it is clear that you have a class imbalance problem. So just by predicting class N your model is getting 86% accuracy. Hence it might misguide you into believing that it is accurate enough but it isnt'. I think Alexis has covered the point very well in the answer below.

Comment: @Kaustubh I think its anomaly detection problem.

Comment: @AnkitSeth I would disagree, since 14 % of data points are of an acceptable class  it is a high number to be considered as anomaly. I don't think a system showing 14 % anomaly is considered as a proper system. In my opinion an condition to be considered as anomaly has to be a very small number of data points.

Comment: @AnkitSeth as per the description of the post says there are 1,00,000 (1 Lakh) rows and 14,000 (14 thousand) only your comment mentions that it has 1,000,000 (1 Million or 10 Lakh) rows. Please correct the Question or Comment Whatever may be the case.

Comment: @Kaustubh Yes you are right about this, there are 100000 rows. Sorry. Still I think it can come under anomaly detection. OP can try both ways and choose that one which fits to his task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data is highly imbalanced, and as per your task, it is a case of **anomaly detection**.

Anomaly detection is a case where your data has one kind of examples in very low number and other in very high number, like your membership division here. Other examples are like detecting flaw in car engines- out of 10000 engines, you get flaw in 40 only. Similarly, members compared to non-members are very less. So treat those person who are members as anomaly.

https://www.allerin.com/blog/machine-learning-for-anomaly-detection

As you can check in above link, there are both supervised and unsupervised methods available for these kind of tasks. I suggest you try those methods.
Also you can check this link for some more explanation-

https://www.datascience.com/blog/python-anomaly-detection

Comment: Thank you, I have solved the problem because of you and @Alexis

Answer (score 5):

Looks like to me this is a classic imbalance binary classification problem (see comments above). What loss are you using ? It looks like your model is predicting the non-membership class because it’s minimising it’s averaging loss. Here are some techniques you might wanna try to solve this issue:

- use regularization
- over sampling the membership class
- under sampling the non-membership class
- select variables, linked to regularization above with l1 and l2 penalties
- feature engineering: you specified you have 30 features but are all of them useful ? How do you preprocess them to feed the model ? Are they numerical or categorical ?

I hope this gives you some ideas about how tackling the problem. Changing the model won’t miraculously solve your issue.

Comment: I would add that there is a *possibility* that a non-linear model, such as XGBoost, could be worth a try as an automated attempt to get a better accuracy. However, the OP still needs to take care. For instance there is no indication that they have any cross-validation or test data, and these become  more important to protect against over-fitting when using non-linear models.

Comment: Thank you, I have solved the problem because of you and @Ankit _Seth

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using regularization, I would use a stratified-shuffle-split when you divide the data in train and test sets in order to deal with class imbalance problem. It is also important to avoid using accuracy directly as a performance measure and, instead of this, use f1-score. Accuracy is not a good indicator of performance if you have class imbalance.

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit ignorant but what is the difference between train_test_split() and stratified-shuffle-split()?

Comment: the stratified keeps the percentage of samples of each class at both train and test sets